# Node JS Asynchronous Execution and Event Emission / Listener Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am new to Node JS and am trying to understand the concurrent / asynchronous execution models of Node.

So far, I do understand that whenever an asynchronous task is encountered in Node, that task runs in the background ( e.g an asynchronous setTimeout function will start timing) and the control is then sent back to other tasks that are there on the call stack. Once the timer times out, the callback that was passed to the asynchronous task is pushed onto the callback queue and once the call stack is empty, that callback gets executed. I took the help of [this](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D) visualization to understand the sequence of task execution. So far so good.

Q1. Now, I am not being able to wrap my head around the paradigm of event listeners and event emitters and would appreciate if someone could explain how even emitters and listeners fall into the picture of call stack, event loops and callback queues.

Q2. I have the following code that reads data from the serial port of a raspberry pi.

```
 const SerialPort = require('serialport');

const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0',{baudRate: 9600}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Port Open Error: ", err);
    }
} )


port.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
})
```

As can be seen from the example, to read data from the serial port, an 'event-listener' has been employed. From what I understand, whenever data comes to the port, a 'data' event is emitted which is 'responded to' or rather listened to by the listener, which just prints the data onto the console.

When I run the above program, it runs continuously, with no break, printing the data onto the console whenever a data arrives at the serial port. There are no continuously running while loops continuously scanning the serial port as would be expected in a synchronous program. So my question is, why is this program running continuously? It is obvious that the event emitter is running continuously, generating an event whenever data comes, and the event listener is also running continuously, printing the data whenever a 'data' event is emitted. But WHERE are these things actually running, that too, continuously? How are these things fitting into the whole picture of the call/execution stack, the event loop and the callback queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1. Now, I am not being able to wrap my head around the paradigm of event listeners and event emitters and would appreciate if someone could explain how even emitters and listeners fall into the picture of call stack, event loops and callback queues.

Event emitters on their own have nothing to do with the event loop.  Event listeners are called synchronously whenever someone emits an event.  When some code calls `someEmitter.emit(...)`, all listeners are called synchronously from the time the `.emit()` occurred one after another.  This is just plain old function calls.  You can look in the eventEmitter code yourself to see a `for` loop that calls all the listeners one after another associated with a given event.

> Q2. I have the following code that reads data from the serial port of a raspberry pi.

The `data` event in your code is an asynchronous event.  That means that it will be triggered one or more times at an unknown time in the future.  Some lower level code will be registered for some sort of I/O event.  If that code is native code, then it will insert a callback into the node.js event queue.  When node.js is done running other code, it will grab the next event from the event queue.  When it gets to the event associated with data being available on the serial port, it will call `port.emit(...)` and that will synchronously trigger each of the listeners for the `data` event to be called.

> When I run the above program, it runs continuously, with no break, printing the data onto the console whenever a data arrives at the serial port. There are no continuously running while loops continuously scanning the serial port as would be expected in a synchronous program. So my question is, why is this program running continuously?

This is the event-driven nature of node.js in a nutshell.  You register an interest in certain events.  Lower level code sees that incoming data has arrived and triggers those events, thus calling your listeners.

This is how the Javascript interpreter manages the event loop.  Run current piece of Javascript until it's done.  Check to see if any more events in the event loop.  If so, grab next event and run it.  If not, wait until there is an event in the event queue and then run it.

> It is obvious that the event emitter is running continuously, generating an event whenever data comes, and the event listener is also running continuously, printing the data whenever a 'data' event is emitted. But WHERE are these things actually running, that too, continuously?

The event emitter itself is not running continuously.  It's just a notification scheme (essentially a publish/subscribe model) where one party can register an interest in certain events with `.on()` and another party can trigger certain events with `.emit()`.  It allows very loose coupling through a generic interface.  Nothing is running continuously in the emitter system.  It's just a notification scheme.  Someone triggers an event with `.emit()` and it looks in its data structures to see who has registered an interest in that event and calls them.  It knows nothing about the event or the data itself or how it was triggered.  The emitters job is just to deliver notifications to those who expressed an interest.

We've described so far how the Javascript side of things works.  It runs the event loop as described above.  At a lower level, there is serial port code that interfaces directly with the serial port and this is likely some native code.  If the OS supports a native asynchronous interface for the serial port, then the native code would use that and tell the OS to call it when there's data waiting on the serial port.  If there is not a native asynchronous interface for the serial port data in the OS, then there's probably a native thread in the native code that interfaces with the serial port that handles getting data from the port, either polling for it or using some other mechanism built into the hardware to tell you when data is available.  The exact details of how that works would be built into the serial port module you're using.

> How are these things fitting into the whole picture of the call/execution stack, the event loop and the callback queue?

The call/execution stack comes into play the moment an event in the Javascript event queue is found by the interpreter and it starts to execute it.  Executing that event will always start with a Javascript callback.  The interpreter will call that callback (putting a return address on the call/execution stack).  That callback will run until it returns.  When it returns, the call/execution stack will be empty.  The interpreter will then check to see if there's another event waiting in the event queue.  If so, it will run that one.

---

FYI, if you want to examine the code for the serial port module it appears you are using, it's [all there on Github](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport).  It does appear to have a number of native code files.  You can see a [file called poller.cpp here](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport/blob/master/src/poller.cpp) and it appears to do cooperative polling using the node.js add-on programming interface offered by libuv.  For example, it creates a `uv_poll_t` which is a poll handle described [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/poll.html).  Here's an excerpt from [that doc](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/poll.html):

> Poll handles are used to watch file descriptors for readability, writability and disconnection similar to the purpose of poll(2).
>
> The purpose of poll handles is to enable integrating external libraries that rely on the event loop to signal it about the socket status changes, like c-ares or libssh2. Using uv_poll_t for any other purpose is not recommended; uv_tcp_t, uv_udp_t, etc. provide an implementation that is faster and more scalable than what can be achieved with uv_poll_t, especially on Windows.
>
> It is possible that poll handles occasionally signal that a file descriptor is readable or writable even when it isn’t. The user should therefore always be prepared to handle EAGAIN or equivalent when it attempts to read from or write to the fd.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. 

So, to summarise and to put it in real simple terms, would it be correct to assume that there is an underlying native code that is continuously polling the serial port and whenever there is data on the port, that code "pushes" an event on the event loop for Node JS to later handle? Is this the reason why, without me adding any continuously running while loops in the java script code, the code seems to be running continuously because it is the underlying native code that is running continuously?

Comment: @nombreinvicto - That appears to be the implementation in that specific module.  For some types of data, you can get an asynchronous notification directly from the OS so polling is not required.  For example, you don't have to poll to get keystrokes from the OS, there is already an OS-level event system for signalling keystrokes (that is interrupt driven at the OS level).